# Short story set in human colony on another planet about an old woman who takes in an android

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space-colonization

I read a short story in one of those "best of the year" sci fi anthologies a year or so ago.  It was about an old woman living in a human colony on an alien planet. She is a hermit and takes in a stranger who turns out to be AI. The old woman was a doctor on earth but is now a hermit. The android's purpose and origin is implied to have been created by the planet's original inhabitants in a kind of factory in an island off coast.

I think it was in one of Gardner Dozois' last collections. Is anyone familiar with this story and can remind me of the name?